# Flex 3 and flash plugin error

Tags: flash, plugins, flex3

I have built a flex 3 application using Flex Builder. I am then embedding it in a portal application but having problems with installing the Flash Player

When i load up my application in Firefox or IE6 (without Flash installed) i get a message where my flex app should be,

("Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page")

When i click to install the plugin i get another error:

(Unknown Plugin(application/octet-stream)).

The plugin does not load and im left hangin. If i then go and manually install the Flash plugin the app works fine however i dont want other users to experience this difficult. Anyone have any suggestions? im using Flex Builder 3 to build the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your flash object into the web page. In the alternative content part (you'll see what I mean, just check the docs), put the following:

```
<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img border="0"
src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" 
alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a>
```

SWFObject should also take care of the situtation when there is a flash player installed, but its version is too low for your app.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Flash on this page work, or do you get the same prompt?
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/

If you get the same prompt, don't let the browser install the plugin.  Instead use the download link on that page and install Flash player manually, preferably as a user with administrative rights.

Reboot your machine and try again.

Comment: flash works fine when manually installed. i just looks like a problem with the instructions Flex application is giving the end user to dowload the Flash Player Plugin or else the way the Flex application is interacting with the underlying Portal

Comment: Your Flex app itself is doing nothing as it hasn't even loaded at this point.  Flex builder generates some html/javascript to wrap the SWF that's generated.  What you could is change the JavaScript to open the download Flash Player page instead when it detects that FP isn't installed.